# How to get the value of child node in firebase

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[My Firebase heirarchy](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lLeJP.png)

I want to get the value of all "user", but calling datasnapshot.getValue is returning null.

```
FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("data").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                    for (DataSnapshot data : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        if (dataSnapshot.getKey().equals("user"))
                             username = data.getValue().toString();

                            Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "sender is " + username, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: you need to create another for-loop 1 level deeper (inside your for-loop)

Answer (score 0):

Create a class with the database structure.

```
public class Data {
    private String msgbody;
    private String mtime;
    private String uname;
    private String user;
    public Data() {
    }
    public String getMsgbody() {
        return msgbody;
    }
    public void setMsgbody(String msgbody) {
        this.msgbody = msgbody;
    }
    public String getMtime() {
        return mtime;
    }
    public void setMtime(String mtime) {
        this.mtime = mtime;
    }
    public String getUname() {
        return uname;
    }
    public void setUname(String uname) {
        this.uname = uname;
    }
    public String getUser() {
        return user;
    }
    public void setUser(String user) {
        this.user = user;
    }
}
```

then

```
for (DataSnapshot snapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
       Data obj = snapshot.getValue(snapshot.getValue(Data.class);
}
```